# Ошибка LNK 1561 (точка входа не найдена)

Tags: c++, winforms, c++-cli

И так есть лаба на Windows Forms (просто просчитать арифметическую,геометрическую прогрессии и число Фибоначчи). Основную логику (3 функции для вычисления прогрессий) вынес в отдельный файл и видимо сделал это очень криво.
Выдает ошибку LNK 1561 - точка входа не найдена. Где и как ее определять в таком приложении для меня загадка. Как и где определить эту точку входа?

Файл MyForm.h (отвечает за саму форму и окна\кнопочки на ней)

```
#pragma once
#include "Progress_func.h"
//куча кода по внешнему виду формы
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        double arif_first = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox1->Text);
        double arif_znam = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox2->Text);
        int arif_num = System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox3->Text);
        double arif_rez = ArifProgress(arif_first, arif_znam, arif_num);
        textBox8->Text = System::Convert::ToString(arif_rez);
    }
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    double geom_first = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox4->Text);
    double geom_znam = System::Convert::ToDouble(textBox5->Text);
    int geom_num = System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox6->Text);
    double geom_rez = ArifProgress(geom_first, geom_znam, geom_num);
    textBox9->Text = System::Convert::ToString(geom_rez);
}
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    int fib_num= System::Convert::ToInt32(textBox7->Text);
    int fib_rez = FibProgress(fib_num);
    textBox10->Text = System::Convert::ToString(fib_rez);
}

};
}
```

Файл MyForm.cpp

```
#include "MyForm.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

[STAThreadAttribute]
void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Project1::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

Файл Progress_func.cpp

```
#pragma once
#include "Progress_func.h"

double ArifProgress(double arif_first, double arif_znam, int arif_num) {
    if (arif_num < 1) return 0;
    return arif_first + arif_znam*arif_num;
}

double GeomProgress(double geom_first, double geom_znam, int geom_num) {
    if (geom_num < 1) return 0;
    double rez = geom_first;
    for (int i = 0; i <geom_num; i++)
        rez = rez*geom_znam;
    return rez;
}

int FibProgress(int fib_num) {
    if (fib_num < 1) return 0;
    int x = 1;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < fib_num; i++) {
        z = x + y;
        x = y;
        y = z;
    }
    return z;
}
```

Файл Progress_func.h

```
#pragma once

double ArifProgress(double arif_first, double arif_znam, int arif_num);
double GeomProgress(double geom_first, double geom_znam, int geom_num);
int FibProgress(int fib_num);
```

Comment: Приложите тексты ошибок

Comment: Там треш полный (русская локализация) 
Ошибка LNK1561 Єюўър тїюфр фюыцэр с√Є№ юяЁхфхыхэр Project1 H:\Project1\Project1\LINK

Comment: Ошибка LNK2005 "double __cdecl ArifProgress(double,double,int)" (?ArifProgress@@YANNNH@Z) єцх юяЁхфхыхэ т MyForm.obj Project1 H:\Project1\Project1\Progress_func.obj 1

Comment: LNK2005 "double __cdecl ArifProgress(double,double,int)" (?ArifProgress@@$$FYANNNH@Z) єцх юяЁхфхыхэ т MyForm.obj Project1 H:\Project1\Project1\Progress_func.obj 1

Comment: Почему он Entry point найти не может, я не знаю - никогда не работал с C++ CLI (ошибка 1561), но 2005 у вас вылетает потому что вы в первом файле включаете CPP файл вместо заголовочного H. У вас каждая функция в два элемента трансляции попадает. Исправьте

Comment: Исправил, действительно теперь одна ошибка 1561 (выглядит однозначно лучше чем 7 старых)

Comment: При выставлении в свойствах проекта Windows выдает LNK2019. Как определить точку входа по прежнему загадка.

Comment: Попробуйте изменить: Свойства конфигурации-Компоновщик-Дополнительно-Точка входа (Properties - Linker - Advanced - Entry Point). Укажите там "Main".

Comment: не помогло, но натолкнуло на верную мысль: в MyForm.cpp void Main поменял на int main и все заработало.

Comment: @LDD Надо полагать, это и есть ответ. Надо бы его оформить соответствующим образом.